# How to namespace a string (eg. 'a(x) + b' => 'Namespace.a(x) + Namespace.b')

Tags: javascript, regex, function, parsing, namespaces

I am looking for a function that will namespace a string, for example if I wanted to namespace the following string with "MyLib",

```
"select('#input') + someconstant * otherconstant"
```

will be changed to

```
"MyLib.select('#input') + MyLib.someconstant * MyLib.otherconstant"
```

btw it takes in a string as an input, and returns another string

The reason I want to do this is because I am writing a user interface which compares my custom math functions with another libraries custom math functions, for example the user might type

```
"factorial(2) + sin(intpow(2, 4))"
```

which would be converted to

```
"MyCustomLib.factorial(2) + MyCustomLib.sin(MyCustomLib.intpow(2, 4))"
/* and */
"OtherLib.factorial(2) + OtherLib.sin(OtherLib.intpow(2, 4))"
```

And then i can use eval() to evaluate it ( dont worry about me using eval, worry about the question :) )

my current function looks like

```
const namespace = (str, ns) => {
  ns = ns + '.'; // add the dot to the namespace
  let s = String(str),
      m, // the result of regex
      re = /\w+/g, // only namespace words
      a = 0; // because there are two strings, and i am
             // only adding to one of them,
             // i have to increase the index to make up for
             // the difference between the two
  while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) { // until there is no more words
    // get the new string (put the namespace in)
    // eg. "(junk) abc (junk)" => "(junk) Namespace.abc (junk)"
    s = s.slice(0, m.index + a) + ns + s.slice(m.index + a);
    a += ns.length; // add to the offset
  }
  return s; // return the parsed string
};
```

where param *str* is the input string, and param `ns` is the namespace

it works, ie.

```
namespace("PI * sin(E)", "Math") === "Math.PI * Math.sin(Math.E)"
```

but it doesnt fully work, ie

```
namespace("23", "abc"); /* === "abc.23" */
```

when it should instead equal "23"

any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use  `re = /[A-z]+/g,` to map only alphabet characters

Comment: this will not work, what about "abc234"? variables can end in numbers